# How to save data to Service-based Database in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, sqlconnection

I have a local Db named NumLeter.mdf whit two tables: LeterTb and NumberTb. I want to insert in NumberTb new values, when the application is running the new values that I inserted show to me correctly as if they had been inserted, but when close the application and clic in Show Table Data the new data was not added in the table. I have instaled EntityFramework v:6.1.3. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LearningVS
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection conexion;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conexion = cConexion.getConexion();
    }

    private void btInsertNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         insertNumber();
    }


    public void insertNumber()
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = conexion;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NumberTb(numberA, numberB, numberC) VALUES(@numberA, @numberB, @numberC)";
        command.Parameters.Add("numberA", SqlDbType.Int, 3).Value = this.txNumberA.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("numberB", SqlDbType.Int, 3).Value = this.txNumberB.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("numberC", SqlDbType.Int, 3).Value = this.txNumberC.Text;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        //testing this either
         /*SqlDataAdapter datAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        NumLeterDataSet dtSet = new NumLeterDataSet();
        datAdapt.FillSchema(dtSet, SchemaType.Source, "NumberTb");
        datAdapt.Fill(dtSet, "NumberTb");
        datAdapt.Update(dtSet.NumberTb);*/ 
    }



    //Also I tried by creating ADO.NET Entity Data Model whit the same result
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new NumDbModel())
        {
            var numbers = new NumberTb()
            {
                numberA = 22,
                numberB = 33,
                numberC = 44,
            };
            db.NumberTBs.Add(numbers);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}}
```

this is where I handle the connection

```
 namespace LearningVS
 {
  class cConexion
  {
    private static SqlConnection conexion;

    public static SqlConnection getConexion()
    {
        if (conexion != null)
        {
            return conexion;
        }
        conexion = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.NumLetersConnectionString);
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            return conexion;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error de conexión" + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void cerrarConexion()
    {
        if (conexion != null)
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Add the context- and the dataclass-source. I think the dataset or the class is wrong implemented.

Comment: As troubleshooting you could output the result of SaveChanges. Should be 1 in your case. You also could log the SQL to console or trace: db.Database.Log += Console.WriteLine;

Comment: Which button are you clicking?

Comment: @kara the result of SaveChanges is 1 as you say, but don't save the data in the .mdf database. I create a data source and the addnew control of the datasource does the same.

Comment: If i'm right "btInsertNum_Click" does work and "button1_Click" does not, correct? If so, your SQLConnection is ok. The question still is how your DbContext (in you case "NumDbModel") looks like. This is where you bind your database (connection/mdf-File) to your datasets (db.NumberTBs). Also it's important to see, how your dataclass "NumberTb" looks like.